# Defining pure virtual functions outside the class definition

Tags: c++

Obviously, inline definition is not allowed.

So, I was wondering **what could be the scenarios where this practice of defining a pure virtual function outside the class definition using the binary scope resolution operator is useful**?

> One scenario I can think of is suppose all the derived classes have some common code/functionality in the pure virtual function definition and that common functionality can be included in the base class definition of the pure virtual function itself and the base class version of the pure virtual function can be called inside the derived classes' definition of the pure virtual function. (Not sure if the syntax works though).

Comment: It is not so obvious (to me) that "inline definition [of a pure virtual function] is not allowed".   The keyword "inline" generates no warning or errors in either place (using gcc 4.8.1 on ubuntu).  So perhaps I am unsure of where you would put the 'inline' to generate a warning/error?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I think OP means defining it inside the class (which makes it automatically inline). I agree that using `inline Foo::f()` works. Although in general virtual functions shouldn't be `inline`, as the compiler decides at runtime which one is being run.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, when you want to invoke common functionality defined in the base class' pure virtual member function.

> (Not sure if the syntax works though).

It works like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Foo
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
};

void Foo::f()
{
    std::cout << "common functionality" << std::endl;
}

struct Bar: Foo
{
    void f() override
    {
        Foo::f(); // call the base pure virtual implementation, common functionality
        std::cout << "derived functionality" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> upFoo{std::make_unique<Bar>()};
    upFoo->f();
}
```

See also Item 34 of Scott Meyers' *Effective C++* for a very detailed discussion of this topic.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious example is when you have a pure virtual destructor. The destructor, while pure, will still be invoked when an object of a derived class is destroyed. Therefore, the destructor is odr-used and requires a definition. In most cases you will just want to explicitly default it. It will still carry out the usual duty of a destructor, invoking the destructors of non-static members and further base classes.